# Gradle sync failed: Unsupported method: NativeArtifact.getAbi()

Tags: android-studio, android-ndk, android-gradle-plugin, android-studio-3.4

I got this error on android studio to 3.4.2 on macOs Mojave although the same project works with the same configurations on my windows laptop.

I'm using gradle-2.10 and ndk verssion ndk-bundle-r12b

I tried to downgrade to earlier version but it doesn't help.
I can't change gradle version because it will cause other compatibility issues

```
INFO - .project.GradleProjectResolver - Gradle project resolve error 
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Unsupported method: NativeArtifact.getAbi()
    at com.android.ide.common.gradle.model.IdeNativeArtifact.getAbi(IdeNativeArtifact.java:97)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.model.NdkModuleModel.populateForFullVariantsSync(NdkModuleModel.java:120)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.model.NdkModuleModel.populateModuleFields(NdkModuleModel.java:102)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.model.NdkModuleModel.<init>(NdkModuleModel.java:94)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.idea.AndroidGradleProjectResolver.populateModuleContentRoots(AndroidGradleProjectResolver.java:258)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.AbstractProjectResolverExtension.populateModuleContentRoots(AbstractProjectResolverExtension.java:96)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.AbstractProjectResolverExtension.populateModuleContentRoots(AbstractProjectResolverExtension.java:96)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.AbstractProjectResolverExtension.populateModuleContentRoots(AbstractProjectResolverExtension.java:96)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.AbstractProjectResolverExtension.populateModuleContentRoots(AbstractProjectResolverExtension.java:96)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.android.configure.KotlinAndroidMPPGradleProjectResolver.populateModuleContentRoots(KotlinAndroidMPPGradleProjectResolver.kt:51)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.AbstractProjectResolverExtension.populateModuleContentRoots(AbstractProjectResolverExtension.java:96)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.TracedProjectResolverExtension.populateModuleContentRoots(TracedProjectResolverExtension.java:62)
```

Comment: Probably the easiest solution would be to upgrade gradle and the Android plugin. Note that the rules of PlayStore require to upgrade NDK, because from this month they require 64-bit binaries for all apps.

Comment: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/139012040